# I am receiving an object as a response that I convert to JSON by using response.json() but then cant get the values out of the json?

Tags: javascript, json

I am sending a request to spotify to get an id value from them to use later in a post request.

```
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
}).then(response => {
    let jsonResponse = response.json();
});
```

this code returns an object that looks like this when converted to jason using response.json()

```
Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Objectdisplay_name: "Jesse James"external_urls: {spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/user/1257754444"}followers: {href: null, total: 3}href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/1257754444"id: "1257754444"images: [{…}]type: "user"uri: "spotify:user:1257754444"__proto__: Object
```

Now I want to extract the id value out. but when I use 
    console.log( jsonResonse.id ) i get an undefined. How to I get that value?

Comment: could you please show me the raw response ?

Comment: `jsonResponse` is a **promise** of the json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a **Promise**

So, simply continue the promise chain as follows

```
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})
.then(response => response.json()) // response.json() returns a Promise
.then(jsonResponse => {
    // here jsonResponse is the json you were looking for
});
```